# Is there a way to change gunicorn log level at runtime?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a [FastApi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) service running on [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) server in a K8s pod. Is there a way to change the log levels / settings at runtime, without restarting the server?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Change the logging.conf/.yaml/.json (if you set the logging config using the gunicorn config file or the `--log-config` parameter) and send SIGHUP to the master process. This will restart the worker processes gracefully.

Long answer: You could change the logging levels dynamically with:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

from within a request, but if you're using more than one gunicorn worker processes (possibly distributed over several machines / pods) only the current process will be affected.

There could be more complex solutions like monitoring the log file (without using --reload option) or listening on sockets to reload config.

Update: I tried reloading logging.conf in worker processes without restarting them (by detecting file changes and reloading gunicorn log config) and although it worked, the config is lost when the master process starts new workers and kills the old ones.

The code is something like this:

```py
import logging
import watchdog

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GunicornLogConfigReloader:
    """A gunicorn log config reloader"""
    _cfg = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not self._cfg:
            self._cfg = self.get_gunicorn_config()
        self.observe_logconfig_changes()

    def get_gunicorn_config(self):
        """Get the gunicorn config object"""
        from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication
        app = WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]")
        return app.cfg

    @property
    def logconfig_filename(self):
        """Get log config file name"""
        return self._cfg.logconfig

    def reload_logconfig(self):
        """Reload the log config file"""
        logger.info("Reloading log config")
        from gunicorn import glogging
        glogging.Logger(self._cfg)

    def observe_logconfig_changes(self):
        from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
        from watchdog.observers import Observer

        class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

            def __init__(self, reloader):
                self.reloader = reloader

            def on_modified(self, event):
                # the modified event is triggered twice, once for the file itself
                # and the second time for the directory, ignore this one
                if event.src_path == self.reloader.logconfig_filename:
                    logger.info("log config has changed, reloading")
                    self.reloader.reload_logconfig()

        observer = Observer()
        fn = self.logconfig_filename
        event_handler = MyHandler(self)
        logger.info(f"Observing {fn} for changes")
        observer.schedule(event_handler, fn)
        observer.start()
```

Just put a line `GunicornLogConfigReloader()` at the bottom of you *main* file.

Comment: Will this enable using logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) to set log level across threads runtime?

Comment: @BjarkeMoholt: of course, threads share the same interpreter, so the log level will remain. (But, be aware, production deployments will have normally several processes, possibly spread over several machines / containers.)